# Use of fork for executing multiple commands

Tags: c++, fork

I have a list of class pointers. I have a function that calls a method from these pointers. Each pointer in the list is a derived class from a main class. What i am currently doing is iterate through the list and call the method of 1st pointer in the list, wait for it to finish, then go to the 2nd class object pointer and call the method and so on.

Now i have like 20 derived classes and it is taking forever to complete through the list. So i wanted to  use fork to execute maybe 4-5 class methods at once so that the whole process is that much fast..

```
list<Myclass *> check;

myfunc(list<Myclass *> check)
{
     for(list<Myclass*>::iterator a= check.begin();a!=check.end();a++)
          (*a)->run();
}
```

this is kinda a skeleton of what i have...
What i want is like each time it will fork and create a child process to execute the command and moveon to the next one...

Comment: is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use fork() to do some work in a child thread. However, once the child process is done doing it's work, it returns and you are not sharing data between them. I am not clear on your implementation but if the intent is to spawn off some processes to do some extra work, then that seems OK, but you probably want a thread, not fork.

Answer (score 0):

You are more likely to want to start a thread  than fork a process. It is easier when there are pointers involved, since pointers can be shared inside a process but not outside.

Also, forking a process has some performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing any memory back with fork though. You probably want a thread. Here's how to do it though:

```
int i = 0;
int n = 4; //or 5;

list<Myclass> check; // You can't use pointers here though, as the memory is not shared.

myfunc(list<Myclass> check)
{
     for(list<Myclass>::iterator a= check.begin();a!=check.end();a++) {
          if(i >= n) {
              wait();
          } else {
              if(fork() == 0) {
                  a->run();
                  exit(0);
              } else {
                  i++;
              }
          }
     }

     // Prevent a voodoo priest from making zombies of these processes.
     while(i-->0) wait();
}
```

Comment: Depends on your OS, or you could look at boost::thread
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread.html

Comment: Night of the living dead! Those forked processes need to be reaped lest they become zombies. Don't depend on the OS to reap those zombies that for you. It's not nice.

Answer (score 0):

> So i wanted to use fork to execute maybe 4-5 class methods at once so that the whole process is that much fast..

As many others have already mentioned, you probably want to use threads rather than fork here. There is a lot more overhead with fork than there is with spawning a new thread.

What others have not said is that spawning a thread or a process does not guarantee a speedup. For example, you might will get a slowdown rather than a speedup if you spawn many more CPU-bound threads at once than the number of available CPUs. What happens is that each of those threads compete with the others for their turn on the limited number of CPUs. A thread will run a little bit of time and then be swapped out for another.

It's a good idea to make the number of active threads less than the number of CPUs available. Even if you do that, you can still run into trouble when some other CPU-bound application happens to be running at the same time.